# For my RDS SQL server master user, I granted denyreader and denywriter to a database. Now I cannot revoke it

Tags: permissions, amazon-rds

For my RDS SQL Server master user, I have granted `denyreader` and `denywriter` to the master user on a database. Now I cannot revoke it.

There are no other db owners to the database that can change permissions. How can I reverse this????

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

From the [RDS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.MasterAccounts.html):

> If you accidentally delete the permissions for the master user, you can restore them by modifying the DB instance and setting a new master user password. For more information about modifying a DB instance, see [Modifying an Amazon RDS DB instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.DBInstance.Modifying.html).

[Performing a password reset](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-master-user-password-rds/) appears to do more than just reset the password, but also resets permissions. I haven't tested this myself, but based on the docs, it would seem that treating it as if you forgot your password should get you back into the account.

Comment: It is not working.It is still the same..

Comment: If the docs aren't accurate, you could try contacting AWS support. Else, I hope you've got good backups...